# Is there a way for a Discord bot to see if a msg author is in a server? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Basically, is there a way to see if a message author is in a particular server using discord.js? I want to make it so if a msg author is in a particular server, it adds a field to Discord.RichEmbed().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but this depends on a few things: Your bot needs to be in the other server as well. Sadly I don't know how you could do this in Discord.js v12`(since they changed a lot of things there but for this you could just check out the docs), but I'll give you the code for v11.5.1 here

```js
let guild = client.guilds.get(serverID); //only works if bot is in the server with serverID as well
let user = guild.members.get(userID);
if (user) console.log("Tada, he is there");
```

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.get(serverID)` should work for v12